Why is this Kirchhoff's formula for wave equation be different from the one on other books?
I'm reading this lectures, on page 15, the author gives the kirchhoff's formula as 
Theorem 4.11 (Kirchhoff's formula). Let $\phi$ be a solution to the equation $\square \phi=F$ with $\phi, F \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{1+3}\right)$. Then we have the formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(t, x)= & \partial_t\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi t} \int_{S_{0, t}(x)} \phi_0(y) \mathrm{d} \sigma(y)\right)+\frac{1}{2 \pi t} \int_{S_{0, t}(x)} \phi_1(y) \mathrm{d} \sigma(y) \\
& +\frac{1}{2 \pi t} \int_0^t \int_{S_{0, t-s}(x)} F(s, y) \mathrm{d} \sigma(y)
\end{aligned}
$$
but on other books, the coefficient of the first two terms is $\frac{1}{4\pi t}$, does this lecture has some errors?
